# Identify raster data for many xy coordinates

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, xy, identify

I do not have much experience with GIS. Currently, I have two raster files in ArcMap. I will have to derive data from these rasters for over 5000 xy coordinates. Below I described the approach I am currently using. However, it is very time consuming like this. Anyone who knows a better approach?

- use go to xy tool
- enter x and y manually
- use identify tool and click on the xy
- copy values of both rasters to Excel

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Spatial Analyst Licence, you can use the [Extract Values to Points too](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/extract-values-to-points.htm)l which:

> Extracts the cell values of a raster based on a set of point features
>   and records the values in the attribute table of an output feature
>   class.

If your 5000 xy coordinates are not a Feature Layer, you can follow [these steps](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/adding-x-y-coordinate-data-as-a-layer.htm) to convert a table (*e.g.* a csv or Excel file) to a Point Feature Layer.

Comment: @Pauline Great! If this answer solved your question, please mark it as accepted. If you solved it other way, please add that solution as an answer so future readers can benefit from it.